# I've installed PHPunit on my system and set the settings in Netbeans but i still can't create PHPUnittests

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, settings

Well title says most of it. I have installed Netbeans 8.0.1 then i've installed both the skeleton generator and the phpunit using PEAR. All the .bat files are in the C:/bin. When i go to the Netbeans settings of phpunit and add both the .bat files in the right place i still can't use PHPUnit. Even when i try to do what is written in the tutorials and clicking my right mouse button on a class i still can't create a PHPUnit test nor can i use any of the annotations that should be available after installation of PHPUnit

Comment: You need to provide more details. How are you trying to create the tests? If from NetBeans, I believe there should be opened output window with log from creating tests (if not, use Window->Output to open it and try to create tests again to see the log)

Comment: yes i saw a few wrong images on the net appereantly it changed in Netbeans 8.0.1 i fixed it now thanks a lot for looking into it though